# one back-button click lowers a soft-keyboard and exits activity at the same time

Tags: android, android-button, back, android-input-method

I am starting my softkeyboard in my ActivityB with this lines in my manifest

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityB"
  android:label="@string/title_activity_activity_b"
  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible" >
</activity>
```

Now I would like that when I press a back button I exit(finish) the activity immediately. I would like to press back button only once to exit the activity.

Right now I have to first press back button once to lower the soft-keyboard and press the back button again for the second time to exit activity.

Is this possible and how can I do that? I tried various common techniques from  this site but none of them worked. I use LG L50 for development.

**EDIT**: I am extending activity and not appcompatactivity

**EDIT 2**: The program works now, here is the code

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}}
```

MyEditText.java

```
package com.example.actionbarimagetest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MyEditText extends EditText implements OnClickListener {

    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    }

    public MyEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    public MyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    }

    public void FlashBorder()
    {
        //do some custom action
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        EditText txt = (EditText) v;
        txt.selectAll();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            System.out.println("KEYCODE BACK");
            ((Activity)getContext()).finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.example.actionbarimagetest.MyEditText
        android:id="@+id/edtTaskName"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just override activity method and finish explicitly

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
finish();
}
```

**UPDATED2**

Yes, this doesn't work for such case. But I've tried few solutions and one of them did work. You need to extend EditText and override method:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            ((Activity)getContext()).finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event);
    }
```

**Note:**
don't forget to replace your previous `EditText` in layout xml with new extented class

Comment: It doesn't work. I still have to press the back button twice. I tried that already.

Comment: check again, it should be there. see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#onKeyPreIme(int, android.view.KeyEvent)

Comment: I am extending activity not appcompatactivity, maybe that is the reason.

Comment: Extend EditText class, not activity

Comment: I extended EditText class and then tried MainActivity.finish(); and I got compile error "Non static member finish() cannot be referenced from a static context..."

Answer (score 1):

call the following function on your backbutton wherever and whatever:

```
 yourMethod()   
    {
// close keyboard
    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) TempActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchBox.getWindowToken(), 0);

    //close activity
    YourActivity.finish(); 
 }
```

for backpressed of android device do as:

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

yourMethod();
YourActivity.finish();
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work also, If I replace YourActivity with ActivityB I get non static method finish cannot be referenced ...

Comment: then call yourMethod(),  in onpause();

Comment: I can't call it from anywhere because this method won't compile.

Comment: Then i'll try to find more solutions for you.

Answer (score 0):

`Activity.onBackPressed()` won't work, because it's being called after (and if) nothing else handled the back button (which IME does).

Override `Activity.dispatchKeyEvent()` instead:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```